# For customizing google maps:

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, google-maps

My objective for this project is to be able to implement custom objects in my iphone app to interact with Google maps. Ex. a Command Button to do X event.

My question is this: Would it be better to work with javascript in an html file to suit my needs, then host it on my web server and call it by using a UIWebView in my app.

Or customize it by using the iOS MapKit framework if that's event possible?

Any information, suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.